# azure-mobile-services Use of LocalDb

Tags: azure-mobile-services, localdb

I want to use Azure Mobile App Services to store data offline. I already have on my client a localDb database and I don't want to use SQLite if possible :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync#how-sync-works

The documentation said :
"A local store is the data persistence layer on the client device. The Azure Mobile Apps client SDKs provide a default local store implementation. On Windows, Xamarin and Android, it is based on SQLite. On iOS, it is based on Core Data."

Can I/have you already used another DB on the client ? How to do it with LocalDb ?

Thanks you

Comment: The implementation is : https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore/MobileServiceSQLiteStore.cs is there another for localDb ?

Comment: AFAIK, azure mobile app client SDKs only provide the SQLite implementation, if you really need to use other LocalDb instead of the default one, you need to write your custom `MobileServiceLocalStore`. Per my understanding, since you are using azure mobile apps with the offline sync feature, you'd better use the implementation provided by Azure side.